# React-Native resets my app when it is in background

Tags: android, react-native, timer, background, reset

I'm developing a `Pomodoro Timer` in `React-Native`.

**In foreground:**
the user interface tracks the remaining time by subtracting the *arrival date minus the current date*.
In addition, it tracks completed cycles.
(the `Pomodoro` tecnique states that every 4 cycles there is a long break).
`cycles`, `finish_date` and `time_remaining` are used as `state` variables (i do use `hooks`) in order to update the DOM properly (and for some logic too).

**In background:**
an alarm is set to notify the user when time is up (`react-native-alarm-notification`).

*If the app remains in foreground all the time, it works exactly like it should.* But if meanwhile I does use other apps or if I simply put my app in background, *most of the times* the app resets so I lose all the progress.
**I guess the operating system, most of the times, resets the app when it is in background mode.**

So it may notify when time is up, But on the UI part, it's like the app has been launched for the first time (but in reality, it only came from background mode to foreground).
Basically its state returns to default.

I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

**P.S.** I did some tests, **actually Android kills the app in two scenarios**: 1 - If it stays in background for some minutes 2 - If there are heavy apps running. I guess both problems are memory related, I tried to set battery performances to "not optimized" but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If youre using react-navigation, try using this:

```js
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs: [
    {
      label: 'Navigation',
      screen: 'example.Types',
      icon: require('../img/list.png'),
      title: 'Navigation Types',
      overrideBackPress: true
    }, {
      label: 'Actions',
      screen: 'example.Actions',
      icon: require('../img/swap.png'),
      title: 'Navigation Actions',
      overrideBackPress: true //here the magic happens
    }
  ]
})
```

By accord of [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2728) issue, the code should make your app minimize instead of killing the process.

Or, if you're not using react-navigation, try using [react-native-minimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-minimize), like as follow:

```
npm install --save react-native-minimize
react-native link react-native-minimize
```

then:

```js
import React from "react";
import {BackHandler} from "react-native";
import RNMinimizeApp from 'react-native-minimize';

[...]

ComponentWillMount(){
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
    RNMinimizeApp.minimizeApp();
  });

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress')
  }

  [...]

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't exit the app via back button, I disabled it. To exit the app I do use the center button, and to bring it to foreground I do use the processes tab of Android. The fact is that, sometimes it works in background, most of the times it doesn't. Should I bind the RNMinimizeApp to the AppState events?

Comment: @MatteoVeraldi On my app i use `StartForeground()` with java, not react-native, and it works pretty well, you already tried it? Sadly it creates a running notification. 
Other thing that i do, is use the AppState event to define wich route to lead when the app come from the brackground.

I dont know if this going to work, but you can try put react-native-minimize to run when the app goes to the background state.
Hope it works

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to read about `StartForeground()` .
By the way I did some tests, actually Android kills my app in two scenarios:
1- If it stays in background for minutes;
2- If there are heavy apps running to save memory;
I need to find a solution for the first scenario. I hope `StartForeground` will help.

Comment: Also, check if is'nt something related to your android version. Some time ago i faced problem with my app don't working on the lockscreen when a call is received. Turn out that it was the android blocking the permission of it, and there wasn't a fix.

Comment: Have you found the answers you were looking for? If you have, can you post them here?

Comment: The answer for the app being killed? @Yossi

Comment: Yes. Prevent the app from being killed.
Also, did you test on iOS?

Comment: Yes i did. And it worked pretty fine for me. (The react-native-minimize solution). Can you test it?